# Generate XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to create some XML from a XML file using PHP, but i cant get it to work

**The XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<streams>
  <stream>test</stream>
</streams>
```

**The PHP**

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/xml");
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("t.xml");

  $html = "<?xml version='1.0'>";
  $html = $html . "<streams>";
  foreach($xml->stream as $stream) 
  {
    $html= $html . "<stream>";
    $html = $html . "<![CDATA[" . $stream->title . "]]>";
    $html= $html . "</stream>";
  }
  $html = $html . "</streams>";

  echo $html; 
?>
```

**The Error**

```
Error: This page contains the following errors: error on line 2 at column 1: 
Extra content at the end of the document Below is a rendering of the page up
to the first error.
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: What is the problem??? Why its not working?? what is the error.. Can you explain???

Comment: explain what is the issue show your effort and error you are getting

Comment: Error:
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Answer (score 2):

I would use php [simplexml](http://php.net/simplexml) to build the xml, not from strings

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
$streams = $xml->addChild('streams');
$steams->addChild('stream', 'data');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Just as a tip, there is a shorthand for concatenating strings:

```
$html = "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
$html .= "<streams>"; 
...
```

Comment: "Beside concatenation in PHP does not work this way. it's like this:" Why? You mean `$html = $html . 'a'` doesn't work and `$html .= 'a'` works?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the OPs string concatenation; it will work, if a bit unwieldy. I would suggest what you demonstrate, but it's not a requirement. Also, the OP is using SimpleXML to load the file, which appears to be where the problems resides. After that, outputting a concatenated XML string can be exported like this, if again unwieldy and not recommended. The problem lies elsewhere, even though these are good suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: the xml is broken, it has to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-------------------^
```

(the question-mark is missing, it's also missing inside the PHP-script)

Then: there is no title-element inside `<stream/>`

It will work as expected with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<streams>
  <stream><title>test</title></stream>
</streams>
```

Comment: Demo: http://codepad.org/NwD2INxf

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work with the following code. I dont know if its the best way, but it works.
I would have typed this as a comment but i couldnt get the "code" format to work.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>";
  $source = "t.xml";
  $stream = new SimpleXMLElement($source,null,true);

  echo "<streams>";
  foreach($stream as $stream) {
    echo "<stream>";
    echo "<![CDATA[ . {$stream->title} . ]]>";

    echo "</stream>";
  }
  echo "</streams>";
?>
```